# Excel VBA macro runs after an object has been moved

Tags: excel, vba, automation

1. I know how to assign a macro to a cell and launch when it has changed.
2. I know how to assign a macro to a 'button' and launch it when clicked.
3. I know how to assign a macro to a worksheet and launch when any cell has changed.

But now ..... I have a text box in a chart and wish to have a macro launch AFTER the text box has been moved to a new location.  Currently, I click on a 'button' after I move the text box and this works well.  I would like to eliminate the final step in order to avoid a problem if the user fails to click the button.

Comment: There's no event for this.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no built-in Event associated with a worksheet property or characteristic you wish to monitor, you can always use an **Application.OnTime** macro to monitor the item.

For example the *TopLeftCell.Address* of a *Shape* can be monitored from call to call and action taken if the property changes.

Some some information see [OnTime](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/OnTime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can found what you want [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2).